# racket in geiser: switch language in live REPL to plai-typed

Tags: racket, read-eval-print-loop, typed-racket, geiser, plai

I've seen hits all around this basic issue, but nothing to help with, in particular, `plai-typed`. So, I can start a racket REPL in geiser, then type `(require typed/racket)` and it seems to take, i.e., I'm ready to go with basic typed racket. Normally, `typed/racket` is activated by having `#lang typed/racket` at the top of a source code file, then loading it. Likewise `#lang plai-typed` is how to use the specific "Programming Languages Applications Interpretations" racket language in source code. But then how can I switch to the plai-typed language in a running geiser racket REPL? Even better would be how to do this in an org-mode babel source code block.

Answer (score 1):

In a Geiser REPL buffer, you could do `C-c C-m plai-typed` to get access to the `plai-typed` language. Additionally, if you're working with a Racket file, you could open that file in Emacs with `C-x C-f /path/to/foo.rkt` and then do `C-c C-a` to load the file into a Geiser REPL (it will create a new one if there is no existing REPL). This has the same effect as `C-c C-m`, but it will also run any code in the file. Note that the `C-c C-a` approach won't work in non-file buffers because the `geiser-mode-switch-to-repl-and-enter` function uses the Geiser `,enter` command and it tries to supply `,enter` with a path, which obviously won't work if you're in a buffer that's not associated with a file.